# An urn probability problem

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose that $M$ balls are distributed among two urns and at each time point one of the balls is chosen at random, removed from its urn and placed in the other one. Now, in the long run the probability that a ball is in urn 1 is $1/2$. Is this because of time-reversibility ? I am understanding it intuitively, but how to prove it formally ?

Comment: molecules, or balls?

Comment: @user40314: what is the difference ?

Comment: @user103623:Let's settle it as molecular balls. What do you mean by time reversibility? Also, do you mean the probability that the ball is in Urn 1 is 1/2? And, BTW, I think what you say is not correct; it depends on which of the $M$ balls is chosen to be removed.

Comment: Maybe you should include that each ball is just-as likely to be removed.

Comment: @DBFdalwayse: I think I have used the word "random".

Comment: @user103623: you're right, my bad.